# How can I open a .csv file stored in my emulator without having Microsoft excel installed?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-file

I want to open a .csv file stored in the Files app under downloads folder in my emulator, and I do not have Microsoft Excel installed. How can I open the .csv file on my emulator then?

Comment: Files cannot be stored in apps. You can open it in any plain text editor.

Comment: When I click on the file, it says 'Can't open file'.

Comment: Add a .txt extension to the file name (with the Files app) and try again.

Comment: Are you just trying to view the file? If so, the easiest thing may be to use `adb pull` command to copy it to your computer and then open it with whatever you want. https://adbshell.com/commands/adb-pull

Comment: I tried here. Indeed Files app does not find suitable apps.

Comment: I am opening it using google drive then, use sending it to my google drive.